# Odd behavior of rowForView and selectRowIndexes in NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa

I have a source list view in my app that's set up to be view based. I then added a badge/button to my cells via this method;

> First subclass NSTableCellView, add an IBOutlet for an NSButton and a
>   @synthesize/@property statement to it. Then open the NSTableCellView
>   that should have a badge in Interface Builder. Set it's class to your
>   newly created subclass and add a button to it. Set the button style to
>   "inline" and it's type to "switch".
>
> Now select the NSTableCellView again and connect the NSButton IBOutlet
>   to your added button. That's it. You can now call e.g. [[cellView
>   button] setTitle@"123"]] to set the rows badge label to 123 or any
>   arbitrary string.

This worked great, but clicking the badge doesn't actually select that row, so I added a click handler to the button.

```
- (IBAction)sourceListBadgeClicked:(id)sender {
    NSUInteger selectedRow = [self.outlineView rowForView:sender];
    if (selectedRow == -1) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"click row: %lu", selectedRow);

    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
    [self.outlineView selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
}
```

I can see the handler get called, but selectedRow is always returned as 0, and selectRowIndexes doesn't actually select the row (I hard-coded to 1 just to test).. Is there something I'm missing in how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it really helps to bind the IBOutlet for the view you're trying to manipulate.. Rookie mistake on my part.